# javascript library which emulates Windows' WScript object?

Tags: javascript, emulation, wsh

I'm looking for an emulation, in javascript, of the WScript object. I've started by creating such an object and defining methods and properties that work like the WScript object. My goal is to wrap the functionality I need and then take it in a different direction.

The reason for doing this is to avoid wholesale changes to a large body of JScript scripts. I'd prefer simply to globally swap "WScript" with (e.g.) "MyWScript" and leave all the ".Echo" and ".StdOut.Write" etc things to be handled by the new object's same-named handlers.

What I haven't looked at is extending the WScript object itself.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, is there a WScript clone/workalike/emulation out there somewhere?

**LATER**

WScript object doesn't seem to be able to be extended. Not like String, for example.

**A COUPLE OF DAYS LATER**

Hey, I'd even take a JScript.NET implementation if there was one!

Comment: Most of the methods of the WScript object have no javascript analogue, because they require features which vanilla javascript doesn't allow for security reasons. Those few which do are so trivial that you should be able to implement them yourself.

Comment: Ok, I admit it: I'm lazy.